# NameError: Name 'Tweepy' not defined (Python)

Tags: python

**Edit:** *This is why people new to Python should read books first... thanks for pointing out my really basic error, guys.*

I have no idea what I'm doing so bear with me, here.

I have this code:

```
from credentials import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

my_file=open('The Story of the Volsungs.txt','r')
file_lines=my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()

def random_line(afile):
    line = next(afile)
    for num, aline in enumerate(afile):
      if random.randrange(num + 2): continue
      line = aline
    return line

def tweet():
    for line in file_lines:
        try:
             print(line)
             if line != '\n':
                 api.update_status(line)
                 sleep(3600)
             else:
                pass
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            sleep(2)

tweet()
```

and it gives me this error (username not *'d out in the actual thing):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\J*****\Desktop\IzzieBot\TweetBot\run_bot.py", line 4, in <module>
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
NameError: name 'tweepy' is not defined
```

I don't know what's wrong or what it needs me to change, the error is so vague.

Comment: You call `tweepy...` before `import tweepy`...

Comment: You're trying to use Tweepy on the third line before you've imported it. That entire chunk seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Change the import order like below :

```
from credentials import *

import tweepy
from time import sleep

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```